# Confusion about the new tag hover-text wording

Tags: discussion, tags, tooltips

The previous wording in the tag hover-text listed the number of "subscribers" in the top left. Now I'm seeing "followers", and a *substantially* larger number of them. For example, in the [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) tag, I saw yesterday that there were 7 subscribers. Now I see this:

[image]

Does "followers" imply the number of people that have [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) listed in their interesting tag list? I can't imagine that many people suddenly began subscribing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's indeed the number of people who have it in the interesting tag list. The nearby star implies that, and clicking it also increases the number by 1.

Comment: So now it's a popularity contest!