# 1.3k followers?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, feed, tag-bubble

Checking the [matlab]-tag, I noticed that SO says that there are 1.3k followers - a few days ago it was less than 10. Is this a bug or has the tag really become so popular?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confusion about the new tag hover-text wording](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75075/confusion-about-the-new-tag-hover-text-wording)

Comment: That is a _fantastic_ dupe, @gnostradamus!

Comment: I eat fantastic dupes as my breakfast. This one will be on my sandwich tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Followers" is equal to number of people who have favorited (aka interesting-ed) the tag plus the number of email subscribers.

It does not reflect RSS subscribers, as we do not track that.

Comment: I already expected something like that :) Higher counts looks more appealing.

Comment: Does this include wildcard interesting or just exact?

Comment: Wildcards are not supported in the counts.  If you hover over a wildcard in your interesting list the count is for the tag portion not including the wildcard chars.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. I see the same explosive increase on other tags. I can think of three reasons for this:

1. It is a relatively new feature which is not 2 weeks old yet if I am correct, people have yet to discover it and subscribe for it. Keep in mind that SO has already over a million pageviews on a daily basis.
2. The amounts are not real-time and only recalculated on a daily basis or two.
3. They added the amount of users who have added the tag to *Favorite Tags* to make it look better.

It can also be a combination of any of those.